# CPU Scheduler Algorithm

Tags: c, cpu, scheduler, critical-section

I'm trying to simulate that my two processes who executes in two different cpu enter the critical section. When both processes' instruction become "CS", I would like to send one of them to the blocked queue. However, even I give the sequence of instructions of two processes same and while they are working in different CPUs in parallel, they both enter the critical section in my simulation code. Can you please analyze my code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
void execute(CPU *cpu)
{
fetch(cpu);
while(cpu->instruction=="NI") {
    //printf("instruction : %s, instructionNo: %d, totalExecution in cpu:%d \n", cpu->instruction, cpu->instructionNo, cpu->totalExecuted);
    Sleep(1000);
    fetch(cpu);
}

if(cpu->instruction=="CS"){
    printf("process %d instruction no: %d",((PCB*) ((cpu->runningProcess)->dataPtr))->processID, cpu->instructionNo);
    WaitForSingleObject(csMutex, INFINITE);
        if(csBoolean==FALSE) {
            csBoolean==TRUE;
        }
        else if(csBoolean==TRUE) {
            printf("process %d suspended.",((PCB*) ((cpu->runningProcess)->dataPtr))->processID);
            ReleaseMutex(csMutex);
            contextSwitch(cpu);
            return;
        }
    ReleaseMutex(csMutex);

    printf("process %d entered its critical section.\n",((PCB*) ((cpu->runningProcess)->dataPtr))->processID);
    Sleep(3000);

    WaitForSingleObject(csMutex, INFINITE);
        csBoolean=FALSE;            
    ReleaseMutex(csMutex);

    ((PCB*)((cpu->runningProcess)->dataPtr))->instructionNo = cpu->instructionNo;
}

else if(cpu->instruction!="NI"){
    contextSwitch(cpu);
}
}
```

Comment: How do you know that's what's happening?

Comment: Both prints that "process entered its critical section". Before I release the csBoolean(setting it to FALSE), I make it wait 3 seconds for the other process. Even though the other process and this one has the same sequence of instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, stupid Visual Studio didn't want to bother me about this annoying syntax error:

```
 if(csBoolean==FALSE) 
  {
          csBoolean==TRUE;
  }
```

Comment: logical error? whatever? shouldn't it tell me that? hey, it's not in a condition or whatever, did you mean that csBoolean=FALSE? Why would I wanna do something like that?

Comment: Is is valid syntax so yes it's a logical error. I think that it may be difficult for the IDEs to parse these types of "errors". Imagine that this is the simplest case. But what happens if csBoolean==TRUE, might be inside a printf() statement for example? The last of course is not a problem.

Comment: Heh, nice catch, if I had a cent for everytime that happened to me :) . And I also think it should have been caught by any self respecting IDE (result is ignored and no side effect occurs)